# Can't access IBMQ (NameError: name 'IBMQ' is not defined)

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

When I type this: `IBMQ.load_account()`, I am getting this error. What does this mean, and how can I rectify it?

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-beb09c0bf764> in <module>
----> 1 IBMQ.load_account()

NameError: name 'IBMQ' is not defined
```

Comment: @met927 I have the same problem, I did install the ibm provider using "pip install qiskit-ibmq-provider" as said in the answer. still I am getting the same error. I am actually reproducing a code given in IBM summer-school youtube, so there should be something wrong with the installation or python version I have?

Comment: What's your qiskit version? `from qiskit import __qiskit_version__`

Comment: Uh I already fixed it. I had a typo mistake

Answer (score 1):

Please check you have `qiskit-ibmq-provider` installed. You can do this by running `pip show qiskit-ibmq-provider` in a terminal. If this returns a warning that it isn't installed, you can then install it using the command `pip install qiskit-ibmq-provider`.

Then go back to your code and make sure you have the statement `from qiskit import IBMQ` before this line of code.

That should take care of things.